# Recursive Function, setTimeout, and 'this' keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, this, settimeout

Let's say that I want to invoke a function with the onClick method.  Like this:

```
<li class="inline" onclick="mve(this);" >TEMP</li>
```

AND I have a JS function that looks like this:

```
function mve(caller){
caller.style.position = "relative";
caller.style.left = (caller.style.left+20) +'px';
var foo = setTimeout('mve(caller)', 2000);
}
```

My problem is that the element (which caller refers to) is undefined after the initial onClick call.  At least this is what Firebug is telling me.

I'm sure it's an easy solution, so how about just a simple explanation of why, and how?

Also if I run it like so:

```
function mve(caller){
caller.style.position = "relative";
caller.style.left = (caller.style.left+20) +'px';
}
```

I would think the element would move 20px right on every click, however that is not the case.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout()` executes a string parameter in the global scope so your value of `this` is no longer present nor is your argument `caller`.  This is one of many reasons NOT to use string parameters with setTimeout.  Using an actual javascript function reference like this and it's quite an easy problem to solve getting the arguments passed accordingly:

```
function mve(caller){
    caller.style.position = "relative";
    caller.style.left = (caller.style.left+20) +'px';
    setTimeout(function() {
        mve(caller)
    }, 2000);
}
```

For the second part of your question, `caller.style.left` is going to have units on it like `20px` so when you add `20` to it, you get `20px20` and that's not a value that the browser will understand so nothing happens.  You will need to parse the actual number out of it, add 20 to the number, then add the units back on like this:

```
function mve(caller){
    caller.style.position = "relative";
    caller.style.left = (parseInt(caller.style.left), 10) +20) + 'px';
    setTimeout(function() {
        mve(caller)
    }, 2000);
}
```

Something that is missing from this function is a way for it to stop repeating.  As you have it now, it goes on forever.  I might suggest passing in either a number of iterations like this:

```
function mve(caller, iterationsRemaining){
    caller.style.position = "relative";
    caller.style.left = (parseInt(caller.style.left), 10) +20) + 'px';
    if (--iterationsRemaining) > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            mve(caller, iterationsRemaining)
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Also, you might be curious to know that this isn't really a recursive function.  That's because the `mve()` function calls `setTimeout()` and then finishes right away.  It is `setTimeout()` that executes the next iteration of `mve()` some time later and there is no accumulation on the stack frame of multiple function calls and thus no actual recursion.  It does look like recursion from a glance at the code, but isn't technically.

Comment: Thank you.  Not only did this answer my questions, but the extra insight and clear presentation made the material easily digestible; very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that caller goes out of scope after the first call. You could preserve it by creating a variable with global scope that preserves the value of caller:

```
var globalCaller;
function onClickEvent(caller) {
    globalCaller = caller;
    mve();
}

function mve() {
    globalCaller.style.position = "relative";
    globalCaller.style.left = (caller.style.left+20) +'px';
    var foo = setTimeout('mve()', 2000);
}
```

This is really ugly, though. You'll create much cleaner code by passing the id of the li element, and then calling getElementById() instead. Or better yet, use jQuery and use $("#id") syntax instead.

Comment: Cleaner to use a closure per jfriend00's answer.